# Invalid syntax after FOR statement

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

I have this piece of code that splits a string with a comma and prints each element:

```
prefixes="item1,item2,item3"

for prefix in prefixes.split(","):

   print prefix
```

Now, when I try to execute the code above, I get the following error:

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):   (no code object) at line 0   File "example.py", line 21

```
    print:
    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried chaging the code to the following:

```
prefixes="item1,item2,item3"

for prefix in prefixes.split(","):

   try:

   print prefix
```

But then I get the following error:

> ```
>     try:
>     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

This should be very simple but it seems that everything I put after the FOR statement becomes invalid.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Fix your indentation in the post.

Comment: @codehorse -- That would loop over individual characters ...

Comment: The code button is the one with the braces.

Comment: What's your overall purpose with this script? The `try` makes us think you're doing something other than *just* printing items from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular script you need to put in an `except`. Unless you're doing something you're not telling us, this will accomplish the `print`.

```
prefixes="item1,item2,item3"

for prefix in prefixes.split(","):
   try:
     print prefix
   except:
         pass
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Turns out it was the indentation that was causing the error. It's working fine now.